# angular 4: I generated component and run the build command? there is should be some errors?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

ERROR in /home/salim/Development/www/kpittu/src/$$_gendir/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts (32,32): Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'DashboardComponent'.

ERROR in /home/salim/Development/www/kpittu/src/$$_gendir/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngfactory.ts (32,44): Property 'editor' does not exist on type 'DashboardComponent'.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/home/salim/Development/www/kpittu/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

Comment: What was the name of the component that you generated? And what command did you type to run the build? What version of cli are you using?

Comment: Which build you are running like prod , aot

Comment: Serve working fine?

Comment: Share your component code

Comment: @RajaMohamed: serve working fine...

Comment: @AniruddhaDas: `code`ng build --prod --env=prod

Comment: @user5500750: `code` ng build --prod --env=prod

Comment: @user5500750: node version: 8.0.0; angular-cli: 1.2.0: os: linux x64...

Comment: I ran into this with Angular CLI version 1.2.2 and resolved by upgrading to 1.3.1

Comment: What is Property 'admin' ? Have you created anything by this name? If yes can you share that pease of code

Comment: @JoshuaColvin: thank you, I will upgrade my ng-cli

Comment: @RajaMohamed: `code` <app-tinymce
  [elementId]="admin-editor"
  (onEditorKeyup)="keyupHandlerFunction($event)">
</app-tinymce>

Comment: When I run build without --prod it's work fine

Comment: This is my dashboard component: ` import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  keyupHandlerFunction(data): void {
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }

}
 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you need to rename the variable 'admin-editor'  to 'admin_editor' in Component and Html files.

```
<app-tinymce [elementId]="admin_editor"  (onEditorKeyup)="keyupHandlerFunction($event)"> </app-tinymce>
```